# On the semantics of `srun ... >output_file` for parallel tasks

Tags: slurm

Sorry, this question requires a lot of build-up, but in summary, it's about the conditions under which many parallel instances of `srun ... >output_file` will or won't lead to the clobbering by some process/task of the output produced by some other process/task.

---

**CASE 0: bash only (no SLURM)**

Suppose that `prog-0.sh` is the following toy script:

```
#!/bin/bash

hostname >&2

if [[ $JOB_INDEX = 0 ]]
then
    date
fi
```

This script prints some output to `stderr`, and possibly prints the current date to `stdout`.

The "driver" script `case-0.sh` shown below spawns `$NJOBS` processes, all writing to `prog-0-stdout.txt`:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $( seq 0 $(( NJOBS - 1 )) )
do  
    JOB_INDEX=$i ./prog-0.sh >prog-0-stdout.txt &
done
```

After running

```
% NJOBS=100 ./case-0.sh 2>prog-0-stderr.txt
```

...my expectation is that `prog-0-stderr.txt` will contain 100 lines, and that `prog-0-stdout.txt` will be ***empty***.

My expectation pans out:

```
 % wc prog-0-std*.txt
  100  100 3000 prog-0-stderr.txt
    0    0    0 prog-0-stdout.txt
  100  100 3000 total
```

The explanation for these results is that, when `NJOBS` is sufficiently large, it is likely that, for some sufficiently high value of `$i`, the redirection `>prog-0-stdout.txt` will be evaluated *after* the "designated job", the one `JOB_INDEX` 0 (and the only one that sends output to `stdout`) has written the date to `stdout`, and this will therefore clobber whatever output was earlier redirected by the "designated job" to `prog-0-stdout.txt`.

BTW, the value of `NJOBS` needs to be high enough for the results to be as I've just described.  For example, if I use `NJOBS=2`:

```
% NJOBS=2 ./case-0.sh 2>prog-0-stderr.txt
```

...then not only will `prog-0-stderr.txt` contain only 2 lines (not surprisingly), but `prog-0-stdout.txt` will contain a date:

```
% cat prog-0-stdout.txt
Wed Oct  4 15:02:49 EDT 2017
```

In this case, all the `>prog-0-stdout.txt` redirections have been evaluated before the designated job prints the date to `prog-0-stdout.txt`.

---

**CASE 1: SLURM job arrays**

Now, consider a very similar scenario, but using SLURM instead.  The script `prog-1.sh` is identical to `prog-0.sh`, except that it examines a different variable to decide whether or not to print the date to `stdout`:

```
#!/bin/bash

hostname >&2

if [[ $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID = 0 ]]
then
    date
fi
```

And here's the corresponding "driver" script, `case-1.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -t 1
#SBATCH -p test

#SBATCH -e prog-1-%02a-stderr.txt
#SBATCH -n 1
#SBATCH -a 0-99

srun ./prog-1.sh >prog-1-stdout.txt
```

Like `case-0.sh`, this script redirects the output of its main step to a single file `./prog-1-stdout.txt`.

*Importantly*, this same file will be seen by all the nodes that run `./prog-1.sh` for this job.

If I now run

```
sbatch case-1.sh
```

...I get 100 files `prog-1-00-stderr.txt` ... `prog-1-99-stderr.txt`, containing 1 line each, and an *empty* `prog-1-stdout.txt`.  I assume that the earlier explanation also explains why `prog-1-stdout.txt` is empty.

So far so good.

---

**CASE 2: SLURM tasks**

Finally, consider one more SLURM-based case, this time using the core script `prog-2.sh` and the driver script `case-2.sh`.  Again, the only change in `prog-2.sh` is the variable it examines to decide whether or not to print the date to `stdout`:

```
#!/bin/bash

hostname >&2

if [[ $SLURM_PROCID = 1 ]]
then
    date
fi
```

And here is `case-2.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -t 1
#SBATCH -p test

#SBATCH -e prog-2-stderr.txt
#SBATCH -N 10
#SBATCH --tasks-per-node=10

srun -l ./prog-2.sh >prog-2-stdout.txt
```

As before, `prog-2-stdout.txt` is visible by all the nodes handling the job.

Now, if I run `sbatch case-2.sh` and wait for the batch job to finish, then `prog-2-stderr.txt` contains 100 lines (as expected), but, *to my surprise*, `prog-2-stdout.txt` is *not* empty.  In fact, it contains a date:

```
% cat prog-2-stdout.txt
01: Wed Oct  4 15:21:17 EDT 2017
```

The only explanation I can come up with is analogous to the one I gave earlier for the results I got when I ran

```
% NJOBS=2 ./case-0.sh 2>prog-0-stderr.txt
```

If this explanation is correct, my concern is that the fact `case-2.sh` worked better than expected (i.e. prog-2-stdout.txt ends up with the right output) is just a coincidence, having to do with the relative timing of concurrent events.

---

Now, at long last, my question is:

**Q:** does SLURM guarantee that a `prog-2-stdout.txt` file that contains the output generated by the designated task (i.e. the one that prints the date to `stdout`) will not be clobbered when the `>prog-2-stdout.txt` redirection gets evaluated by one of the non-designated tasks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a misconception on how srun works. In CASE 1 the usage of srun is irrelevant as it's used in batch scripts to start parallel jobs. In CASE 1 you only have one task, so

`srun ./prog-1.sh >prog-1-stdout.txt` is equivalent to:

`./prog-1.sh >prog-1-stdout.txt`

CASE 2 is different, as you have more than 1 task. In that case, `srun -l ./prog-2.sh >prog-2-stdout.txt` is only evaluated once, and srun will take care of spawning 10*10 tasks. srun will redirect the output of all the tasks to the master node of the job, and it will be the one writing to `prog-2-stdout.txt`.

So you can be sure that in this case there will be no clobbering of the output file as it is evaluated only once.

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, I definitely have misconceptions about how `srun` works (ditto for `sbatch`, btw).  One part of your answer I don't understand is when you write "srun will redirect the output of all the tasks to the master node of the job".  How does `srun` know which one is "the master node of the job"; in my options I did not specify it.

Comment: srun is the responsible to spawn the processes, so the output of all the processes will be redirected to the node running the srun process (the master, aka the first node of the job)

Comment: Thanks!  As you pointed out, I have misconceptions about `srun`, etc.  I still have only a very fuzzy understanding of what these commands do.  The man pages do not give me the big picture I'm missing...  Thanks for your help.  Things are getting clearer, bit by bit.