# how to write sbatch to handle multiple job in slurm

Tags: shell, slurm

I have two executable file need to run: `a.out` and `b.out`.

(1) I want run the `a.out` on two node, each node have one `a.out` process.

(2) I want run the `b.out` on two node,the node is same in (1), but each node have two `b.out` processes.

My naive code shown as follow

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --nodes 2
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node 2

srun a.out
srun b.out
```

But it can not handle the needs above. How can I write sbatch to achieve that?

I apologize if it is a stupid problem. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we have 3 node and want run first job A and job B.
The job A should run on per node with 1 process.
The job B should run on per node with 5 process.

Thus the sbatch file `sbatch_input.sh` can be written that:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --nodes 3
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node 5
#SBATCH -p cnall

# job A
srun --nodes 3 --ntasks=3 hostname
echo "-------------------------------"
# job B
srun --nodes 3 --ntasks-per-node=5 hostname
```

run the script with sbatch

```
sbatch ./sbatch_input.sh
```

The result shown that

```
c05b01n06
c05b01n08
c05b01n07
-------------------------------
c05b01n06
c05b01n08
c05b01n07
c05b01n06
c05b01n06
c05b01n06
c05b01n06
c05b01n08
c05b01n08
c05b01n08
c05b01n08
c05b01n07
c05b01n07
c05b01n07
c05b01n07
```

Here not using the number 2 in problem in case of misunderstand.

- Reference

https://slurm.schedmd.com/srun.html

[How do the terms "job", "task", and "step" relate to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46506784/how-do-the-terms-job-task-and-step-relate-to-each-other)