# understanding sacct's maxRSS -- Why are there two rows for a job?

Tags: slurm, sacct

I have the output from `sacct --format="jobID,CPUTime,MaxRSS" -j 66930332_195`. I know maxRSS reports a value roughly equivalent to max memory usage. However, what do the two different rows in maxRSS refer to?

```
  JobID    CPUTime     MaxRSS
------------ ---------- ----------
66930332_195   00:05:15
66930332_19+   00:05:15   4688356K
66930332_19+   00:05:15      2376K
```

Thanks in advance! I haven't been able to find this documented anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `%20` like this to show the JobID in its entirety,

```
sacct --format="jobID%20,CPUTime,MaxRSS"
```

you would probably see something like this:

```
  JobID          CPUTime     MaxRSS
------------     ---------- ----------
66930332_195     00:05:15
66930332_195.0   00:05:15   4688356K
66930332_195.1   00:05:15      2376K
```

The first row corresponds to the job itself and the other ones correspond to the [jobs steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46506784/how-do-the-terms-job-task-and-step-relate-to-each-other). That should correspond to the number of `srun` calls you do in your submission script.

Comment: So the maximum memory used by this job was `4688356K`, no? If so, why is the job's MaxRSS empty (first line)? Wouldn't it make sense to have max(of all MaxRss)?

Comment: Yes that would be handy ; some people use the [seff](https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm/blob/master/contribs/seff/seff) helper tool to compute the `max(of all MaxRss)`