# Interpretation of output from sacct: meaning of ex+

Tags: slurm

I would like to know if a job is using one or two CPUs, based on the interpreation of the following sacct. I have searched documentation about the meaning of the ex+ row but found nothing: how should I interpret that row?

```
       JobID      State  Timelimit               Start                 End    Elapsed      NCPUS
------------ ---------- ---------- ------------------- ------------------- ---------- ----------
18948126        RUNNING   10:10:00 2020-04-26T15:59:39             Unknown   00:17:44          1
18948126.ex+    RUNNING            2020-04-26T15:59:39             Unknown   00:17:44          1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+` indicates that the field is truncated because too long to be displayed. The command `sacct --format=JobID%30` should show the full JobID (if not, just put a larger number).

The multiple rows correspond to the multiple steps of the job (the first one for the script, then one per task). `[.JobStep]` indicates the job step. See [JobID in the sacct doc](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sacct.html) as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46532581/6352677).